# Prevent browser back button to redirect to the previous page in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have used the following article to create a POC on showing an Session expire warning message in a asp.net mvc2 application. 
http://www.fairwaytech.com/2012/01/handling-session-timeout-gracefully/

I have made one change in the code as mentioned below:

`location.href = expireSessionUrl;` in the endSession method to the following code:

```
window.location.replace(expireSessionUrl);
```

and once user clicks on the Log Out button present in the Session warning message dialog box he is navigated to the LogOut view. But here if he clicks the browser back button he is navigated to the previous page.

I have the following modified Expire method as mentioned bleow:

```
[Authorize]
public virtual ActionResult Expire()
{
Session.Clear();
FormsService.SignOut();
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
return Redirect(“/”);
}
```

Can you please guide me in resolving the issue.

Thanks In Advance
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your cache expired, try this:

```
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

or from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y18he7cw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

or you can use [Response.CacheControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524721.aspx) to control how a page is stored in a users cache

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is not working still now also. I am able to click the browser back button and navigate to the previously visited page.